# How to find the difference between two timestamp values in mule?

Tags: timestamp, mule, difference

I am getting the timestamp value in the format "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS" eg: "2016-05-22 01:02:36.909093". I need to calculate the difference between the two values of the same format mentioned above. Could anyone help to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Mule, but on the Java side it is easy.

## java.time

Assuming your input string is in UTC, parse it as an `Instant` after replacing that SPACE in the middle by a `T`.

```
String input = "2016-05-22 01:02:36.909093".replace( " " , "T" );
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input );

Instant now = Instant.now();

Duration duration = Duration.between( instant , now );
```

You can ask the `Duration` for its length as a total number of hours or total of days or a total of minutes etc.

Oddly, in Java 8 the `Duration` class is lacking convenient methods for interrogating the parts such as hours or minutes. In Java 9 this lacking is remedied by “getPart” methods.

The `Duration` class can parse and generate strings in the standard ISO 8601 format. For example, an hour and a half is `PT1H30M`.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a period using dataweave directly. If your payload was:

```
{
"date1":"21-07-2016 10:00:00.000000",
"date2":"22-07-2016 11:11:11.111111"
}
```

Then this dataweave gives your period:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%type fdate = :localdatetime {format: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"}
---
{
period: 
payload.date1 as :fdate - payload.date2 as :fdate
}
```

Which will look like this as output:

```
{
  "period": "PT25H11M11.111111S"
}
```

Obviously you can then refactor to a different format or output target.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java for that and use Joda date library.

Answer (score 0):

We need to go for a groovy to check with that, below is the code that can help you

```js
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss");
                
if(flowVars.lastRunDateTime==null||flowVars.lastRunDateTime=='0')
flowVars.lastRunDateTime=flowVars.currentRunDateTime;

log.info("last run date time"+flowVars.lastRunDateTime);
log.info("current time"+flowVars.currentRunDateTime);

               date1=flowVars.lastRunDateTime;
               date2=flowVars.currentRunDateTime;
       
              
                   d1 = null;
                      d2 = null;
                      d3 = null;
                     
                     d1 = format.parse(date1);
                     d2 = format.parse(date2);
                     
                     diff=d2.getTime()-d1.getTime(); 
                      
                      t=diff/60000;
                     
                     log.info(t + " total Minutes ");                           
                                                   
                   if(t>30)
                   {
                     log.info("initial Time"+d1 );
                     calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                     calendar.setTime(d1);
                     calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, ${time.gap});
                     d3= calendar.getTime();
                     log.info("Final Time"+d3);
                     flowVars.lastRunDateTime=format.format(d1);
                     flowVars.currentRunDateTime=format.format(d3);
                     log.info("last run date time"+flowVars.lastRunDateTime);
                     log.info("current time"+flowVars.currentRunDateTime);
                   }                     
                    
              
flowVars.put('IM_START_DATE', flowVars.lastRunDateTime.substring(0,10));
flowVars.put('IM_START_TIME' , flowVars.lastRunDateTime.substring(10,16) + '01');
flowVars.put('IM_END_DATE' , flowVars.currentRunDateTime.substring(0,10));
flowVars.put('IM_END_TIME' , flowVars.currentRunDateTime.substring(10,16) +'00');
```